# Use AJAX response to update select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This code can fetch data from a database then return it to a select option:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.renew', function() {
  var user_id3 = $(this).attr("id");
  $.ajax({
    url: "../controller/fetch_single.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      user_id3: user_id3
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      $('#bus_type').html(data.type);
    }
  })
});
```

The AJAX is successful and returning the JSON but the select option is still returning blank instead of the data coming from AJAX. What am I doing wrong?

Example output of `data`:

```
{
    "id":"575",
    "bus_name":"THIS LOVE",
    "type":"RERE",
    "address":"SDF"
}
```

Comment: We cannot answer your question without knowing if the AJAX request was successful, what it's response was and what your HTML looks like

Comment: Did you validate the data using `console.log(data.type)` ??

Comment: dude as i said the ajax request was successful, this is the return json {"id":"575","bus_name":"THIS LOVE","type":"RERE","address":"SDF"} and i want to return the data.type to select option but it just return blank

Comment: could you provide us with an example output of `data` inside `success()` and your HTML?

Comment: You are suppose to wrap ajax response as `object` and then `html` it..

Comment: what do you mean? how?

Comment: The select should have the value allready.. what you are doing is setting the json between <select> and </select>

Comment: You have to create valid html or elements from the json data. It doesn't happen magically by itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click', '.renew', function() {
    var user_id3 = $(this).attr("id");
    $.ajax({
        url: "../controller/fetch_single.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            user_id3: user_id3
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            // If the option is in the select
            $('#bus_type').find('option[value="'+data.id+'"]').prop('selected', true);

            // Or if the option is not there yet
            var $option = $('<option></option>').html(data.type).attr('value', data.id).prop('selected', true);
            $('#bus_type').append($option); // Adds the new option as last option
            $('#bus_type').prepend($option); // Adds the new option as first option
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: i tried this  $('#bus_type').find('option[value="'+data.id+'"]').prop('selected', true); and it worked . Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your HTML is:

```
<select id="bus_type">
    <!-- no content yet -->
</select>
```

and your response is :

```
{
    "id":"575",
    "bus_name":"THIS LOVE",
    "type":"RERE",
    "address":"SDF"
}
```

Then your `success()` method would just print the following:

```
<select id="bus_type">
    RERE
</select>
```

which is not a valid HTML for a `<select>`.

**Your JS should look like this for it to work**:

```
$(document).on('click', '.renew', function() {
  var user_id3 = $(this).attr("id");
  $.ajax({
    url: "../controller/fetch_single.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      user_id3: user_id3
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      $('#bus_type').html("<option value='"+ data.type +"'>"+ data.type +"</option>");
    }
  })
});
```

**Or like this if you want to preserve the existing options**:

```
$(document).on('click', '.renew', function() {
  var user_id3 = $(this).attr("id");
  $.ajax({
    url: "../controller/fetch_single.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      user_id3: user_id3
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      $('#bus_type').append("<option value='"+ data.type +"'>"+ data.type +"</option>");
    }
  })
});
```

The `success()` method would print the following:

```
<select id="bus_type">
    <option value="RERE">RERE</option>
</select>
```

*If you would provide us some HTML I could edit my answer to your specific needs.*

Comment: dude i tried this and it is okay, but the other options are removed

Comment: the data.type is the only one remaining on the option and the other options are removed

Comment: I edited my answer to preserver previous options.
see `$('#bus_type').html($('#bus_type').html() +"<option value[...]`
Did that solve your problem?

Comment: no dude the other options are there but it does not return the data coming from ajax.

Comment: Ever heard of `.append()` ?

Comment: it just select my first option

Comment: @Brainfeeder good suggestion. Been a while since i used jquery.